# Rails ActiveRecord retrieving associated data with two has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Let's say you have a `Licence` model that `has_many: :seats` and the `Seat` model `has_many: :customers`.

What I want to get back is an ActiveRecord object of all the customers on a `Licence`. Is there a way to do this?

I have a solution `licence.seats.includes(:customers).flat_map(&:customers)` but this will return an Array object which is not what I am looking for.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Use has_many through option:

```
class Licence
    has_many :seats
    has_many :customers, through: :seats
end
```

Now you can get customers by

```
licence.customers
```

Comment: Can you please explain this, as i can't figure out how would this work , as `seats ` is not an intermediate tables to establish `many-to-many` association between `licences and customers` . :)

Comment: @Gabbar The has_many :through association is also useful for setting up "shortcuts" through nested has_many associations. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 1):

[`joins`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins) does the job:

```
Customer.joins(:seat).where(seats: { licence_id: licence.id })
```

It returns `Relation`, just as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using joins/includes this can be efficient for large records.

```
class Licence
    has_many :seats

    def customers
      #customer belongs_to seat
      Customer.where(seat_id: seats.pluck(:id))
    end
end
```

Query -

```
licence.customers
```